# Copy files from Android to Xubuntu, Need a workaround for files not being copied

Tags: linux, android

How do I copy ALL files from an non-rooted Android device to Xubuntu ? I am able to copy the folder containing everything in Android, but receive an error that certain files cannot be copied. When I click 'retry', Linux cannot seem to copy them still.

FYI, I am trying to pull all of my Nook books from an Android Tablet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying for hours to recover books that I feel Barnes and Noble stole from me.

Thank you

Comment: Many options: with Bluetooth, with WiFi, with USB MTP mode, with ADB. Which one did you try?

Comment: It's also probable that you won't be able to. Many files in Android are not readable, even in ADB, without root access.